# Automatically find Arduino without IP

Tags: arduino

I have a RaspberryPi which is going to act as the server for my Arduinos which are connected to the same network.

However, the RaspberryPi is unable to automatically connect to the Arduino. I have to hardcore each Arduino IP address into the server.

Is there anyway for my server to search the network and identify the arduino so it could be added into the server database automatically. Or the other way round, the arduino find the server ip and attempts to connect to it.

My server is running on node.js

Comment: dhcp? if the Pi runs dhcp, then the mere act of getting an IP will tell the arduinos what the server IP is (e.g. it'll be the dhcp server IP). If not, you can use a dns TXT record to specify the server ip, and the dhcp setup would tell the arduinos what the dns server IP is as well.

Comment: @MarcB Im trying to implement it such that. I can move this whole setup to any router and the whole system will be connected. The IP will be different as they are all running on dhcp

Comment: Probably the raspberry has a name (I think it is called the "WINS name"). Let's say its "raspberrypi". If the arduinos try to connect to "raspberrypi", the router should be able to resolve the IP like a DNS. The advantage of WINS is that it requires no configuration... Once the arduinos can find the raspberry, they can send him their IP address...

Answer (score 0):

If both the Rasbpi and the Arduino are connected to the same router, they are in the same subnet. You can let tell your server periodically scan the subnet ip range.

I am not familiar with node.js but here are some good starting points for network scanning:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/ip
- https://github.com/jas-/node-libnmap

Answer (score 0):

From your server install the latest nmap binary then expose that tool to node.js like so:

'$ npm install --save libnmap'

Then use the discover method available to find all connected devices per network interface.

var nmap = require('libnmap');
nmap.discover(function(err, devices) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(JSON.stringify(devices));
});

Answer (score 0):

I would use mDNS to find the Arduinos. The only requirement for the RPi is to be running Avahi, to have the appropriate multicast port open, and to have the mDNS resolver installed and configured. There are several Arduino libraries available that implement mDNS; a quick Google search finds a few.